Access token updating in mirrored repositories
I have a local Gitea instance with mirrored repositories from GitHub and GitLab. One of my access tokens has expired, so I would like to know how to update the access token in the mirrored repositories.

You can either do that through Gitea UI
or if you have a lot of repositories to update, the token is in the git config  of each repository you have mirrored and you need to update it
Gitea does not keep the token elsewhere in its own database or provide an api call to update the token
here a sample from one of mine (removed any sensititve details)

[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://oauth2:[here is the token]@github.com/[org]/[repo].git
fetch = +refs/:refs/
mirror = true
fetch = +refs/tags/:refs/tags/

